# how to enable and use DTLS in socat command

Tags: socat, dtls

How to enable and use DTLS in socat command in **linux**.
I tried to enable `DTLS` with the below commands and test, but I see a `TCP` handshake getting established between client and server and there is no `DTLS` handshake initiation

CLIENT:

```
socat OPENSSL:x.x.x.x:4433,verify=0,cert=esdsap256certkey.crt,cafile=esdsap256.crt,method=DTLS1 -
```

SERVER:

```
socat OPENSSL-LISTEN:4433,reuseaddr,pf=ip4,fork,cert=./esdsap256certkey.crt,cafile=./esdsap256.crt,method=DTLS1
```